# Writing loop over multiple pages with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, loops, mechanize, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to scrape several pages of results from the county search tool here: http://www2.tceq.texas.gov/oce/waci/index.cfm?fuseaction=home.main

But I can't seem to figure out how to iterate over more than just the first page.

```
import csv
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www2.tceq.texas.gov/oce/waci/index.cfm?fuseaction=home.main'

br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open(url)

br.select_form("county_search_form")

br.form['county_select'] = ['111111111111180']
br.form['start_date_month'] = ['1']
br.form['start_date_day'] = ['1']
br.form['start_date_year'] = ['2014']

br.submit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response())

complaints = soup.find('table', class_='waciList')

output = []

import requests
for i in xrange(1,8):
    page = requests.get("http://www2.tceq.texas.gov/oce/waci/index.cfm?fuseaction=home.search&pageNumber={}".format(i))
    if not page.ok:
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.text)

    for tr in complaints.findAll('tr'):
        print tr
        output_row = []
        for td in tr.findAll('td'):
            output_row.append(td.text.strip())

        output.append(output_row)

br.open(url)
print 'page 2'
complaints = soup.find('table', class_='waciList')

for tr in complaints.findAll('tr'):
    print tr

with open('out-tceq.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    my_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    my_writer.writerows(output)
```

I was getting results for just page one in the output CSV. I tried adding the import requests loop after looking at other examples of scrapes using bs4 but got the error message 'ImportError: No module named requests.'

Any thoughts on how I should be looping over all eight pages of results to get them into the .csv?

Comment: You need to [install `requests` module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/) first before you can use it in code, have you?

Comment: So, I installed the requests module on the terminal and ran the code again in the terminal. It still just iterates over the first page but the output file it creates doesn't have contain any records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need `requests` module to iterate through paged search result, `mechanize` is more than enough. This is one possible approach using `mechanize`.

First, get all paging links from current page :

```
links = br.links(url_regex=r"fuseaction=home.search&pageNumber=")
```

Then iterate through paging links, open each link and gather useful information from each page on every iteration :

```
for link in links:
    #open link url:
    br.follow_link(link)

    #print url of current page, just to make sure we are on the expected page:
    print(br.geturl())

    #create soup from HTML of previously opened link:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response())

    #TODO: gather information from current soup object here
```